# función modal en javascript, error con f5

Tags: javascript, modal

Utilizando [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), ejecuto un modal con un mensaje luego de un cierto tiempo de inactividad.

Funciona bien, pero por lógica en este caso si presiono `F5` o cualquier tecla, o si hago clic en cualquier parte, luego de haber excedido el tiempo establecido para la inactividad me redirige al login. Eso lo hace. Pero si presiono `F5` no redirige al login!

La pregunta es ¿Cómo hago para capturar ese evento también y que rediriga al login así presione `F5`?

Les comparto el código Javascript

```
function TiempoActividad() {
    setTimeout("alertamodal()", 3000); // 15 minutos
  }
  function alertamodal(){
        $('#sesionalert').modal('show');
        $('#sesionalert').on('click', function(){
          $('#sesionalert').modal('hide');
          location.href = "<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Users", "action" => "logout")); ?>";
        })
  }
```

Les agradezco de antemano